# Автоматическая генерация UML диаграмм из кода Python

Tags: python-3.x, uml

Я совсем обленился за самоизоляцию.
МНе необходимо построить Action Diagramm  в  UML для класса на Python. Конечно же, имея код под 500 строк с кучей условий и циклов, преспектива делать его руками как-то совсем неприятна. Хотелось бы так - загрузил файл с расширением *.py и диаграмма готова. Я верю, что такое существует, возможно даже онлайн.
Загуглил. Нашел 3-4 ссылки на редакторы.Онлайн не нашел. Скачал. И они как-правило не работают... Сразу скажу, что я скачал PynSource и у меня Ubuntu. И он не правильно обработал код. То есть , вывел только лишь список входных переменных... Подскажите, я уверен, что должна быть какая-то надстройка над PyCharm....

Answer (score 1):

Для решения данной задачи нашлось масса решений
прежде всего Эклипс
[Эклипс](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-pyuml/)

В нем все удобно получилось и собственно говоря на этом вопрос можно закрыть.

[вот вторая ссылка](https://pynsource.com/)Она кстати легко устанавливается через ерминал `sudo snap install pynsource`